# How to get value from the array of the objects present inside object. (javaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have an object like below and it contains an Array of objects,

```
{
  UserId: '634a336122b4b995d25869d5',      
  CategoryId: '620015b6f61454403daba1b4',
  specialUser: [{
        "startDate": "2022-10-3",
        "endDate": "2022-11-3",
        "priceType": 1,
        "price": 199
    },{
        "startDate": "2022-10-3",
        "endDate": "2022-11-3",
        "priceType": 1,
        "price": 199
    },{
        "startDate": "2022-10-3",
        "endDate": "2022-11-3",
        "priceType": 1,
        "price": 199
    }]
}
```

How to get values from specialUser including UserId and CategoryId

Thanks for help....

Comment: no I don't want to sort just iterate and want to get the fields with values from specialUser

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  Accessing properties of an object and/or elements of an array is something that should really be covered in introductory JavaScript tutorials.  It's not clear to me where specifically you're stuck or what isn't working as expected.

Comment: Not from the code shown in the question you aren't.  Have you written some *other* code which is producing an unexpected result?  We can't help with code we can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {
  UserId: '634a336122b4b995d25869d5',      
  CategoryId: '620015b6f61454403daba1b4',
  specialUser: [{
        "startDate": "2022-10-3",
        "endDate": "2022-11-3",
        "priceType": 1,
        "price": 199
    },{
        "startDate": "2022-10-3",
        "endDate": "2022-11-3",
        "priceType": 1,
        "price": 199
    },{
        "startDate": "2022-10-3",
        "endDate": "2022-11-3",
        "priceType": 1,
        "price": 199
    }]
};
```

Basically you can use map and include the parent properties into your specialUser array

```
data.specialUser.map((x)=> {
    x.UserId = data.UserId;
    x.CategoryId = data.CategoryId;
    
    return x;
});
```

Comment: If I use forEach then will it give result.

Comment: yes but on that case you have to use data inside foreach as it will not update